# How to generate all points in Python for 0< x_1+x_2+x_3<1, x_1>0,x_2>0,x_3>0, say dx=0.01

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numerical-methods

How to generate all points in Python for `0<x_1+x_2+x_3<1`, `x_1>0`,`x_2>0`,`x_3>0`, say $dx=0.01$. Trying to use this as grid in solving a constrained optimization problem.

Comment: SO doesn't support LaTeX formatting. Please convert to a more readable format. You can wrap text in `\``s and it will be formatted monospace.

Comment: Thanks for remind me of this

Comment: You should fix the typos in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can randomize two points between 0 and 1, and an additional one described below.
x1 would equal: first point
x2 would equal: abs(first-second)
x3 would equal: another random point in (0, 1 - x1 - x2)

Comment: @ZHU Fixed answer to give also values that sum up to less than 1. I still believe that all valid solutions are distributed uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def frange(x, y, step=0.01):
    while x < y:
        yield x
        x += step

for x1 in frange(0.01, 1):
    for x2 in frange(0.01, 1-x1):
        for x3 in frange(0.01, 1-x1-x2):
            print x1, x2, x3
```

Comment: @NickA: maybe, though in many cases OPs are just begging for ready-made code... Such downvotes are unfair.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thx !